# Error in finding solution of congruence equation by using theorem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was solving $19x\equiv42 \mod(50)$

I had used these following theorem [image]

SO as $19 \cdot 5=95 \equiv -5 \pmod{50}$
 and $42 \cdot 5\equiv -8 \cdot 5 \pmod{50} \equiv -40 \pmod{50}$
SO $-5x\equiv -40 \pmod{50}$ which means  $5x\equiv 40 \pmod{50}$ by using above theorem
$x\equiv 8 \pmod{10}$ so my answer should be $8,18,28,38,48$
But answer is only $18 \pmod{50}$.
AS theorem statement is if and only if all solution must be there 
Where is my mistake?
Is there is any other short method to solve equation?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You did $19 \times 5 =95$ and $42 \times 5 = 210$. You should also do $50 \times 5 = 250$, right? To get $95x \equiv 210 \mod 250$ as the equation (you reduced the coefficients modulo $50$ which is incorrect as my modulus is different now). *Even the modulus is being multiplied by five*. This has only $18$ as a solution, although this is more difficult IMO to see than the initial equation itself.

Comment: Ohh Thanks a lot Sir...I am Doing this mistake from long time.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sir , If I have ax=bmod n now if i know inverse of a then $a^{-1}ax=x=a^{-1}b=mod n $ or  $a^{-1}ax=x=a^{-1}b=mod a^{-1}n $ ? WHat is correct? I am doing this also .But in this case my answer was right

Comment: No, if $ax \equiv b \mod n$ then $x \equiv a^{-1}b \mod \mathbf{n}$, **not** $a^{-1}n$. That is, your first option is correct. See, $a^{-1}$ is a number(equivalence class) : we can multiply by it on both sides of the congruence, but not on the modulus. The lemma given concerns the modulus, however this multiplicative property does not affect the modulus.

Comment: To solve this problem, I would just use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).  The lemma is meant to be invoked when you are solving a problem such as $20x \equiv 35 \pmod{35} \iff 20x = 25 + 35t$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.  If we divide each side of the equation $20x = 25 + 35t$ by $5$, we obtain $4x = 5 + 7t \iff 4x \equiv 5 \pmod{7}$, which we can solve with the extended Euclidean algorithm.